# Classic ASP - Replace unicode characters from Facebook json feed

Tags: unicode, asp-classic

I'm working on an old classic asp site. We are importing Facebook feeds with the Graph API from Facebook. All done by importing the json feed.

In the Graph API Explorer from Facebook all characters in the feed look OK.

However when I import or show the contents of the feed on the screen I get something like this:

*Tra le province di Modena e Reggio Emilia, ai piedi delle prime colline appenniniche, c\u2019\u00e8 una terra speciale. Resa speciale dai suoi abitanti che hanno saputo trasformarla in energia creativa. Parallela alla romana via Emilia che attraversa tutta l\u2019Emilia Romagna c\u2019\u00e8 un\u2019altra strada che da Maranello\u2026*

If I use this tool ([converter](http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php)) (where it says "Converts Unicode Entities to Unicode Text") to convert the string to normal text I get normal text:

*Tra le province di Modena e Reggio Emilia, ai piedi delle prime colline appenniniche, c’è una terra speciale. Resa speciale dai suoi abitanti che hanno saputo trasformarla in energia creativa. Parallela alla romana via Emilia che attraversa tutta l’Emilia Romagna c’è un’altra strada che da Maranello…*

How can I achieve this with classic ASP?

Comment: Need some code here. How are you retrieving the JSON? Client-side? Server-side? Are you using JavaScript? JScript? VBScript? Etc...

Comment: Your JSON library is broken. The string sent by the server is the latter, but your JSON library is giving you the former. File a bug report and consider replacing it.

Comment: I am using this class to retrieve the JSON: http://www.aspjson.com/